# Remove lines with less than 4 characters and more than 3 numbers in bash

Tags: bash

So for example, I have this text file:

```
use
user_99
12345
```

**+10k lines...**

And I want to remove those that have less than 4 characters from the command line,
I've already searched in google but no results came.

Any ideas? : )

I'd also like to remove lines with more than 3 numbers in the beginning.

Comment: Do you want to remove lines that have at least 4 numbers (more than 3) and less than 4 characters or lines that have less than 4 letters (irrespective of the number of digits) or lines that have less than 4 characters _and_ more than 4 numbers? Please show us an example input and your desired output.

Comment: terdon: I want to remove lines like "use" (Has less than 4 characters) **and** lines that have more than 3 numbers, like for example 12345. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed or awk are good choices:

```
sed -rn '/^.{0,3}$/n; /^[0-9]{3,}/n; p' file

awk --re-interval 'length > 3 && !/^[0-9]{3,}/' file
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a GNU sed regex for at least 4 characters as `.{4,}` - then to delete all lines *except* those with at least 4 characters:

```
sed -r '/.{4,}/!d' file
```

Similarly, a line starting with more than 3 consecutive digits would be `^[0-9]{4,}` so to delete all those

```
sed -r '/^[0-9]{4,}/d' file
```

You can combine them either using `-e` or `;`

```
sed -r -e '/.{4,}/!d' -e '/^[0-9]{4,}/d' file
```

or

```
sed -r '/.{4,}/!d ; /^[0-9]{4,}/d' file
```

Note that `.` matches space characters as well as non-space characters - if that is not what you want then you can change it by replacing `.` with a character range or POSIX class such as `[[:alnum:]]`.